# Why Aren't We Able to Set arrival_time in Driving Mode using Google Directions API? (Or Distance Matrix API)

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api, google-distancematrix-api

I'm trying to create a simple app that notifies the users when they need to leave the house to arrive somewhere at a specific time.

For that, I'm trying to use the arrival_time parameter in the API but apparently it doesn't work when the mode is set to Driving. And Developer's Guide clearly says arrival_time for transit mode.

I know it kinda depends on the departure time but still it doesn't make too much sense. Because think about it, I can get that data by guessing a departure time, getting the time_in_traffic parameter, add it to my departure time and compare it with my requested arrival time. If it's not the same, keep calling the API with later or earlier departure times until you get the right departure time.

Why isn't the option to set the arrival_time in driving mode given to us? Is there a reason? Am I failing to see an obvious reason or something?

Google Maps already gives us this feature, I can set the arrival time and get a suggested "Leave around" time in Driving mode. Why doesn't API also support this?

Or at least can anyone suggest me a solution to do this other than that tedious multiple API calls solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature request has been created in public issue tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9579

I can see that Google set status to Neat Idea and created an internal issue #29927572 on November 2, 2016. Hopefully it will be evaluated and implemented one day.

Please star the public issue to express your interest and receive further updates from Google.

Comment: I had searched that issue tracker before but I guess I only searched directions api.

Thank you for the link. I starred it